# Laravel Livewire Click Away to submit

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I haven't been able to find anything relating to an action to submit an update request when we click away. Something like `wire:clickaway = "update( {{ example -> id }} )"`

Essentially, I am trying to create the effect of when a user clicks on the title, it will open an input box. Than when user clicks away, it will save the data that has been updated in the box.

Right now, I got this working with a checkmark icon appearing when the edit is true using Alpine

```
<div x-data="{edit : false}"  >

 <h2 @click="edit = true" x-show="edit === false" >{{$example -> title}} </h2>

 <div x-show="edit === true">
  <input name="title"  type="text" placeholder="{{$example -> title}}" wire:model="title"  >
  <i class="bi bi-check "  wire:click="update({{ $example->id }})" @click="edit = false"></i>
 </div>

</div>
```

I wanted to change this to something like

```
<div x-data="{edit : false}"  >

 <h2 @click="edit = true" x-show="edit === false" >{{$example -> title}} </h2>

 <input x-show="edit === true" name="title"  type="text" placeholder="{{$example -> title}}" wire:model="title" wire:clickaway="update({{ $example->id }})" @click.away="edit = false" >


</div>
```

Is there a way to pass the submit of `update({{ $example->id }})` using the Alpine JS `@click.away`?

Comment: Hi Jakub, maybe you are looking for `wire:change`?

Comment: Brooo! Thanks so much! That works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is what @Dirk Jan said

```
wire:change="update({{ example -> id }})"
```